# How to plot a Parabola and the points using plt?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following list of points:

```
[[1,10],[2,5.49],[3,0.89],[4,-0.14],[5,-1.07],[6,0.84]]
```

I calculated the parabola which goes through those points `y=0.83535714x^2-7.74778571x+17.116`. The values:

```
> print(matrix)
 [[ 0.83535714]
 [-7.74778571]
 [17.116     ]]
```

Also, I have splited the points:

```
points = np.asarray([[1,10],[2,5.49],[3,0.89],[4,-0.14],[5,-1.07],[6,0.84]])
points_x_axis = points[:, 0]
points_y_axis = points[:, 1]
```

Now I want to plot the Parabola and the points. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using Polynomial regression to smooth the graph

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def parabola(x):
    return 0.83535714*x**2-7.74778571*x+17.116

x = np.linspace(0, 9, 100)
y = parabola(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(points_x_axis, points_y_axis)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#Simple plotting    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(points_x_axis, points_y_axis, 'o')
plt.plot(points_x_axis, 0.83535714*points_x_axis**2-7.74778571*points_x_axis+17.116)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can I make it look like "Parabola"?

Comment: @vesii Take a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.polyfit` and `np.polyval`:

```
data = np.array([[1,10],[2,5.49],[3,0.89],[4,-0.14],[5,-1.07],[6,0.84]])
p = np.polyfit(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], 2)
x = np.linspace(0, 9, 100)
y = np.polyval(p, x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], 'k.')
```